# Appending the title property of a variable to this string?

Tags: windows, powershell

I may be using the wrong terminology here, please beer with me.

I have an RSS Feed link here.  I’ve run it against `Invoke-RestMethod` and stored it in a variable called `$Feed`.

If I run :

```
$feed | Format-Table -Property Title, Link
```

I get the data presented nicely like this:

[image]

I would like to print out the all the Titles on the Terminal Prefixing the string `Article Name is:` . One article per line. For example:

```
Article Name is: Fan Art Can Be a Good Thing
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
$feed = Invoke-RestMethod https://www.muddycolors.com/feed/
$feed | ForEach-Object {"Article Name is: $_.Title"}
```

Terminal Outputs:

```
Article Name is: System.Xml.XmlElement.Title
Article Name is: System.Xml.XmlElement.Title
Article Name is: System.Xml.XmlElement.Title
Article Name is: System.Xml.XmlElement.Title
Article Name is: System.Xml.XmlElement.Title
Article Name is: System.Xml.XmlElement.Title
Article Name is: System.Xml.XmlElement.Title
Article Name is: System.Xml.XmlElement.Title
Article Name is: System.Xml.XmlElement.Title
Article Name is: System.Xml.XmlElement.Title
Article Name is: System.Xml.XmlElement.Title
Article Name is: System.Xml.XmlElement.Title
Article Name is: System.Xml.XmlElement.Title
Article Name is: System.Xml.XmlElement.Title
Article Name is: System.Xml.XmlElement.Title
```

What could I be doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In short: In order to embed _expressions_ in an expandable string (`"..."`), you must enclose them in `$(...)`. Notably, this includes property and indexed access (e.g., `$($var.property)`, `$($var[0])`). Only variables _as a whole_ do not require this (e.g., `$var`, `$env:USERNAME`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) to the linked duplicate.